# How to make the two child classes as a key in a Map where key type is a parent class

Tags: java

So, I have a map..

```
Map<Class<? extends ISwarmEntity>, Object>  map = new hashmap;
```

If I were to have multiple classes that extend ISwarmEntity I can't put them all in the map as keys. How would I go about doing this?

Example:

```
Map.put(swarmmob1.class,1);
Map.put(swarmmob2.class,2);
```

`Swarmmob1` will be overwritten by `swarmmob2`

Guys it works. I'm sorry!!

Comment: `Map`s will commonly use a `Set` to store the keys, so yes, identical elements cannot coexist. Can't you map by your current value instead? Are you sure you have to map by classes and not by instances? Otherwise, can't you map by class and lists/sets of values?

Comment: You can have multiple classes that extend `ISwarmEntity` you just can't have the same class because you can't have duplicate keys...

Comment: Why do you think it will be overwritten. As bros05 has mentioned, it will be overwritten only for the same class. not different classes as in your case.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: if I understand correctly what you intend to do, it would be possible to do but exactly that, it's just that the map you constructed will have just 2 entries: one for swarmmob1.class and the other for swarmmob2.class.

Comment: "Map.put(swarmmob1.class,1);
Map.put(swarmmob2.class,2);" no, it won't be overwritten, why do you think that?

Answer (score 2):

Why exactly do you think it doesn't work?
Is it possible you made a different mistake but the generics confused you?

```
import java.util.*;

class MapExtend {

    public static void main (String[] a) {
        Map<Class<? extends I>,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put (A.class, 1);
        map.put (B.class, 2);
        System.out.println (map.get(A.class));
        System.out.println (map.get(B.class));
    }

}

interface I {}

class A implements I {}

class B implements I {}
```

When I compile & run this program it first outputs `1` and then `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Override the hashcode and equals method of different classes which extends ISwarmEntity in order to use them as a key in a HashMap.

But it's a really bad idea, always use immutable objects as a key for HashMap.
Immutabiility is required, in order to prevent changes on fields used to calculate hashCode() because if key object return different hashCode during insertion and retrieval than it won't be possible to get object from HashMap.

Answer (score -1):

What you do is

```
static class BaseClass { }

static class ClassA extends BaseClass { }

static class ClassB extends BaseClass { }

@Test
public void yourCase() throws Exception {
    Map<Class<? extends BaseClass>, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    ClassA x = new ClassA();
    ClassA y = new ClassA();

    map.put(x.getClass(), 1);
    map.put(y.getClass(), 2);

    assertEquals(1, map.get(ClassA.class)); // fails, x and y have same class
}
```

What you want to do is either this

```
@Test
public void testClasses() throws Exception {
    Map<Class<? extends BaseClass>, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put(ClassA.class, 1);
    map.put(ClassB.class, 2);

    assertEquals(1, map.get(ClassA.class));
}
```

Or more likely this - have actual instances as keys:

```
@Test
public void testInstances() throws Exception {
    Map<BaseClass, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    ClassA instanceA = new ClassA();
    ClassB instanceB = new ClassB();

    map.put(instanceA, 1);
    map.put(instanceB, 2);

    assertEquals(1, map.get(instanceA));
}
```

Comment: The OP is clearly using the second method you have mentioned. Not the first.

Comment: Hard to tell, the `swarmmob1` suggests its an instance, `.class` suggests it's a class.